# WebKit transform 3d on Android is not working

Tags: android

I am trying to open the following webpage in Android 2.3.3 browser ...

http://www.webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/morphing-cubes.html

but the animation is not working properly because android 2.3.3 is not supporting webkit transform 3d.

Any idea how to make it work ?

Regards,
Sandesh.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/transforms3d) you can use 3d css transforms only on honeycomb or later. For earlier versions there is nothing you can do other than doing a native app.

Comment: I am trying it in emulator sir, does that make any difference ?

Comment: Yes there is a difference. If you are not using an gpu enabled emulator image then 3d rendering is done with a software emulation. But it might not work even with gpu enabled. Its always best to use a real device when doing anything with opengl.

Comment: Sir, I have bought a honeycomb device and tested the url http://www.webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/morphing-cubes.html in the browser its working great . when i try to load the same url in the webview its not working .. Can you please help me

Comment: You can use a javascript mobile framework (e.g., Wink, Dojo Mobile, etc.) to achieve the same or similar effects.

Answer (score 0):

Try if the following polyfills work, 
they are especially for Internet Explorer, though.

https://github.com/pbakaus/transformie

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/